# Integer overflow in for-loop causing odd behaviour

Tags: c#, for-loop, integer-overflow

Consider the following code. First 5 iterations goes well and then it goes on in an infinite loop spamming 0's.

```
        for (int i = 2; i < 100000; i*=i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

I'm suspecting its because the Integer overflows, and guessing that the default returned value when it overflows is 0.

How would you write this code, so that it does what it is intended to do?

Edit: This is kinda a theoretical example, and i'm just playing around to learn. Is there no way to do this, without changing datatype or checking for 0? Would be nice if it actually threw an exception.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: "the default returned value when it overflows is 0" No. According to the standard, "In an unchecked context, overflows are not reported and
any significant high-order bits outside the range of the result type are discarded."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're right that it overflows.

Rather than just telling you to use `unchecked` to force it to throw an exception, *here is an explanation of **WHY** you get zeros after the 5th result*

Here is the series:

```
2
4
16
256
65536
4294967296  <-  this won't fit into an int
```

in your code, 2,147,483,648 + 1 becomes -2,147,483,648

the 6th value overflows and becomes 0 (4,294,967,296 ends up going from 0 to 2,147,483,648 to -2,147,483,648 and keeps adding back up towards 0 again)

and your `for` modifier clause will then run `0*=0` indefinitely

EDIT: as per your update, use the `checked` keyword to get an exception on the overflow

```
 checked {

    for (int i = 2; i < 100000; i*=i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    } 

  }
```

otherwise use a `long` or `ulong` instead of `int` as both of those can safely store the result of 100000*100000

Answer (score 3):

Use [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) if you want an overflow exception:

```
checked
{
    for (int i = 2; i < 100000; i*=i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }   
}
```

> The checked keyword is used to explicitly enable overflow checking for
>   integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.
>
> By default, an expression that contains only constant values causes a
>   compiler error if the expression produces a value that is outside the
>   range of the destination type. If the expression contains one or more
>   non-constant values, the compiler does not detect the overflow.